# Non-positive-definite forecast error covariance matrix encountered at period 1 ARIMA update

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I am trying to update an ARIMA model after training it. However, this error keeps popping up `Non-positive-definite forecast error covariance matrix encountered at period 1`. Why is it so?

Here's my code if you want to reproduce it:

```
#general
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
import yfinance as yf
from pmdarima.arima import ADFTest

ticker = "0118.KL"
data = yf.Ticker(ticker)
df = data.history(period="max",end="2020-04-30")

df = df.filter(items=['Close'])

n=365
train = df[:-n]
test = df[-n:]

from pmdarima import auto_arima

model = auto_arima(train,trace=True,m=7,error_action='ignore', suppress_warnings=True)
model.fit(train)

forecast = model.predict(n_periods=n)
forecast = pd.DataFrame(forecast,index = test.index,columns=['Prediction'])

model.update(test)
```

Why does this happen? Any insight would be much appreciated.